# Import Selected Column in Text File in DataGrid View C#

Tags: c#, text, import, datagrid

Sorry for my English Grammar, i am Newbie in C# programming.  I would like to make a program to import txt file to datagrid in vb c# but i only like to get the selected column. please see on image my sample text file content.

[image]
I Want only to get column WP  LAT  DIST  BRG the rest is not.
the first and second row which is date "18-OCT-2017"  and name "PILOT-ODESSA" and the last row which is TOTAL not  included.

Thank you very much in advance for help.

Comment: What did you try? we dont do all the work for you

Answer (score 0):

Below is only for reference. You need to understand and use it as required:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = "sample.txt";

            using (var fileRdr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                var columns = fileRdr.ReadLine().Split(",".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

                CreateColumns(columns);

                while (!fileRdr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var lineData = fileRdr.ReadLine().Split(",".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(lineData[0], lineData[1]);
                }

                fileRdr.Close();
                fileRdr.Dispose();
            }

        }

        private void CreateColumns(string[] columns)
        {
            foreach (var col in columns)
            {
                var dataColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                dataColumn.Name = col;
                dataColumn.HeaderText = col.ToUpper();

                switch(col.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "WP":
                    case "LAT":
                        {
                            dataColumn.Visible = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        {
                            dataColumn.Visible = false;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
            }
        }       
    }
```

Output:

[image: Winforms App]

Input File: (Note that instead of space separated - I changed it to be a CSV)

```
WP,LAT,LON,DIST,SPD,MISC
1,10.5,25.3,10,15,AXX
2,11.9,24.1,50,25,BXX
3,20.2,20.9,70,35,CXX
```

Comment: tanx for the help.. its ok with me to import all column but the same format not csv format...